# Neural networks: why don't we use a multi-dimensional learning rate

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, hessian

I've searched a bit on the internet a have found the answer nowhere so I decided to post here.

When confronted to an optimization problem, we know that the sanity of the problem can be characterized by the condition number, which is the ratio of the highest eigenvalue of the hessian over the smallest one.

I am puzzled by the fact that we use a 1D learning rate in neural networks for instance, where we have highly multidimensional problems. Why couldn't we go to the eigenvector's of the hessian basis and from there use a different learning rate for each component (which are then independent) ? 
It seems to me that it would solve sanity problems, but since I can't be the first who thought of this and since this is mentioned nowhere, my thinking is probably wrong.

Answer (score 2):

We *do* use multidimensional learning rates, for example, this is what [optimization algorithms like AdaGrad](http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/) do, they have varying learning rates for each parameter. Using multiple learning rates may not be obvious in case of such algorithms, because you usually initialize them with scalar learning rate, that is re-scaled appropriately for each of the variables by the algorithm.

Comment: Oh thanks ! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

We do.  See work on *Hessian-free learning* by Schraudolph, Pearlmutter, Martens, Sutskever.  Also, relevant is the *natural gradient*.

Essentially, using one learning rate assumes isotropic parabolic loss.   One learning rate for each dimension (a vector of learning rates) assumes axis-aligned elliptic parabolic loss.  A much more general form is to assume a parabolic loss with an arbitrary curvature matrix (the Hessian), but this is typically way too expensive.

Compromises are well-summarized by one of those authors I listed (I forget who, but I can look it up if you want).